# Money format output and also in the textbox

Tags: php

i have here a sample computation, what i want to know is how can it be a money format output.
for example 1000+ 1000 =2000
i want to output it as 2,000.
also , when typing the value , i want it automatically look a money format.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<form name="haha" method="post" >

1:<input type="text" name="num1">

2:<input type="text" name="num2">

Total:<input type="label" name="total">
<input type="submit" value="add" name="submit">

</html>
</form>
<?

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$num1=$_POST['num1'];
$num2=$_POST['num2'];
$total=$_POST['total'];



$total= $num1 + $num2;

echo $total;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$english_format_number = number_format(floatval($total));
echo $english_format_number;
```

Comment: it doesnt work 
Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in C:\wamp\www\trial\add.php on line 60

Comment: Ok then you need to cast your `$total` as a number. See the updated line of code

Comment: can this be applicable on user's key press?

Comment: Nopes, not easily. This is a server side solution since you did not mention or tag JavaScript etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) or its more advanced brother [`money_format`](http://php.net/money-format). This will take care of the server-side for you.

As for the client-side, I would advise against making things change while the user's typing. Just let them type in the number how they want. Bonus points if you allow them to type in thousand separators (since you can just strip them out easily in PHP to get the number itself).

Comment: can you suggest an way to have thousand separators on key press? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript for that, when user change the input value you need to call the function to format the value.

You have to something like this:

```
$("[name^='num']").change(function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
      $(this).val(money_format(format, value));
});
```

Here is the function for monet format :

Ref: https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/strings/money_format.js

```
function money_format (format, number) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // + original by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // + input by: daniel airton wermann (http://wermann.com.br)
  // + bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // - depends on: setlocale
  // % note 1: This depends on setlocale having the appropriate locale (these examples use 'en_US')
  // * example 1: money_format('%i', 1234.56);
  // * returns 1: 'USD 1,234.56'
  // * example 2: money_format('%14#8.2n', 1234.5678);
  // * returns 2: ' $ 1,234.57'
  // * example 3: money_format('%14#8.2n', -1234.5678);
  // * returns 3: '-$ 1,234.57'
  // * example 4: money_format('%(14#8.2n', 1234.5678);
  // * returns 4: ' $ 1,234.57 '
  // * example 5: money_format('%(14#8.2n', -1234.5678);
  // * returns 5: '($ 1,234.57)'
  // * example 6: money_format('%=014#8.2n', 1234.5678);
  // * returns 6: ' $000001,234.57'
  // * example 7: money_format('%=014#8.2n', -1234.5678);
  // * returns 7: '-$000001,234.57'
  // * example 8: money_format('%=*14#8.2n', 1234.5678);
  // * returns 8: ' $*****1,234.57'
  // * example 9: money_format('%=*14#8.2n', -1234.5678);
  // * returns 9: '-$*****1,234.57'
  // * example 10: money_format('%=*^14#8.2n', 1234.5678);
  // * returns 10: ' $****1234.57'
  // * example 11: money_format('%=*^14#8.2n', -1234.5678);
  // * returns 11: ' -$****1234.57'
  // * example 12: money_format('%=*!14#8.2n', 1234.5678);
  // * returns 12: ' *****1,234.57'
  // * example 13: money_format('%=*!14#8.2n', -1234.5678);
  // * returns 13: '-*****1,234.57'
  // * example 14: money_format('%i', 3590);
  // * returns 14: ' USD 3,590.00'

  // Per PHP behavior, there seems to be no extra padding for sign when there is a positive number, though my
  // understanding of the description is that there should be padding; need to revisit examples

  // Helpful info at http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_7.html and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r10.bpxbd00/strfmp.htm

  if (typeof number !== 'number') {
    return null;
  }
  var regex = /%((=.|[+^(!-])*?)(\d*?)(#(\d+))?(\.(\d+))?([in%])/g; // 1: flags, 3: width, 5: left, 7: right, 8: conversion

  this.setlocale('LC_ALL', 0); // Ensure the locale data we need is set up
  var monetary = this.php_js.locales[this.php_js.localeCategories['LC_MONETARY']]['LC_MONETARY'];

  var doReplace = function (n0, flags, n2, width, n4, left, n6, right, conversion) {
    var value = '',
      repl = '';
    if (conversion === '%') { // Percent does not seem to be allowed with intervening content
      return '%';
    }
    var fill = flags && (/=./).test(flags) ? flags.match(/=(.)/)[1] : ' '; // flag: =f (numeric fill)
    var showCurrSymbol = !flags || flags.indexOf('!') === -1; // flag: ! (suppress currency symbol)
    width = parseInt(width, 10) || 0; // field width: w (minimum field width)

    var neg = number < 0;
    number = number + ''; // Convert to string
    number = neg ? number.slice(1) : number; // We don't want negative symbol represented here yet

    var decpos = number.indexOf('.');
    var integer = decpos !== -1 ? number.slice(0, decpos) : number; // Get integer portion
    var fraction = decpos !== -1 ? number.slice(decpos + 1) : ''; // Get decimal portion

    var _str_splice = function (integerStr, idx, thous_sep) {
      var integerArr = integerStr.split('');
      integerArr.splice(idx, 0, thous_sep);
      return integerArr.join('');
    };

    var init_lgth = integer.length;
    left = parseInt(left, 10);
    var filler = init_lgth < left;
    if (filler) {
      var fillnum = left - init_lgth;
      integer = new Array(fillnum + 1).join(fill) + integer;
    }
    if (flags.indexOf('^') === -1) { // flag: ^ (disable grouping characters (of locale))
      // use grouping characters
      var thous_sep = monetary.mon_thousands_sep; // ','
      var mon_grouping = monetary.mon_grouping; // [3] (every 3 digits in U.S.A. locale)

      if (mon_grouping[0] < integer.length) {
        for (var i = 0, idx = integer.length; i < mon_grouping.length; i++) {
          idx -= mon_grouping[i]; // e.g., 3
          if (idx <= 0) {
            break;
          }
          if (filler && idx < fillnum) {
            thous_sep = fill;
          }
          integer = _str_splice(integer, idx, thous_sep);
        }
      }
      if (mon_grouping[i - 1] > 0) { // Repeating last grouping (may only be one) until highest portion of integer reached
        while (idx > mon_grouping[i - 1]) {
          idx -= mon_grouping[i - 1];
          if (filler && idx < fillnum) {
            thous_sep = fill;
          }
          integer = _str_splice(integer, idx, thous_sep);
        }
      }
    }

    // left, right
    if (right === '0') { // No decimal or fractional digits
      value = integer;
    } else {
      var dec_pt = monetary.mon_decimal_point; // '.'
      if (right === '' || right === undefined) {
        right = conversion === 'i' ? monetary.int_frac_digits : monetary.frac_digits;
      }
      right = parseInt(right, 10);

      if (right === 0) { // Only remove fractional portion if explicitly set to zero digits
        fraction = '';
        dec_pt = '';
      } else if (right < fraction.length) {
        fraction = Math.round(parseFloat(fraction.slice(0, right) + '.' + fraction.substr(right, 1))) + '';
        if (right > fraction.length) {
          fraction = new Array(right - fraction.length + 1).join('0') + fraction; // prepend with 0's
        }
      } else if (right > fraction.length) {
        fraction += new Array(right - fraction.length + 1).join('0'); // pad with 0's
      }
      value = integer + dec_pt + fraction;
    }

    var symbol = '';
    if (showCurrSymbol) {
      symbol = conversion === 'i' ? monetary.int_curr_symbol : monetary.currency_symbol; // 'i' vs. 'n' ('USD' vs. '$')
    }
    var sign_posn = neg ? monetary.n_sign_posn : monetary.p_sign_posn;

    // 0: no space between curr. symbol and value
    // 1: space sep. them unless symb. and sign are adjacent then space sep. them from value
    // 2: space sep. sign and value unless symb. and sign are adjacent then space separates
    var sep_by_space = neg ? monetary.n_sep_by_space : monetary.p_sep_by_space;

    // p_cs_precedes, n_cs_precedes // positive currency symbol follows value = 0; precedes value = 1
    var cs_precedes = neg ? monetary.n_cs_precedes : monetary.p_cs_precedes;

    // Assemble symbol/value/sign and possible space as appropriate
    if (flags.indexOf('(') !== -1) { // flag: parenth. for negative
      // Fix: unclear on whether and how sep_by_space, sign_posn, or cs_precedes have
      // an impact here (as they do below), but assuming for now behaves as sign_posn 0 as
      // far as localized sep_by_space and sign_posn behavior
      repl = (cs_precedes ? symbol + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') : '') + value + (!cs_precedes ? (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + symbol : '');
      if (neg) {
        repl = '(' + repl + ')';
      } else {
        repl = ' ' + repl + ' ';
      }
    } else { // '+' is default
      var pos_sign = monetary.positive_sign; // ''
      var neg_sign = monetary.negative_sign; // '-'
      var sign = neg ? (neg_sign) : (pos_sign);
      var otherSign = neg ? (pos_sign) : (neg_sign);
      var signPadding = '';
      if (sign_posn) { // has a sign
        signPadding = new Array(otherSign.length - sign.length + 1).join(' ');
      }

      var valueAndCS = '';
      switch (sign_posn) {
        // 0: parentheses surround value and curr. symbol;
        // 1: sign precedes them;
        // 2: sign follows them;
        // 3: sign immed. precedes curr. symbol; (but may be space between)
        // 4: sign immed. succeeds curr. symbol; (but may be space between)
      case 0:
        valueAndCS = cs_precedes ? symbol + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + value : value + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + symbol;
        repl = '(' + valueAndCS + ')';
        break;
      case 1:
        valueAndCS = cs_precedes ? symbol + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + value : value + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + symbol;
        repl = signPadding + sign + (sep_by_space === 2 ? ' ' : '') + valueAndCS;
        break;
      case 2:
        valueAndCS = cs_precedes ? symbol + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + value : value + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + symbol;
        repl = valueAndCS + (sep_by_space === 2 ? ' ' : '') + sign + signPadding;
        break;
      case 3:
        repl = cs_precedes ? signPadding + sign + (sep_by_space === 2 ? ' ' : '') + symbol + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + value : value + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + sign + signPadding + (sep_by_space === 2 ? ' ' : '') + symbol;
        break;
      case 4:
        repl = cs_precedes ? symbol + (sep_by_space === 2 ? ' ' : '') + signPadding + sign + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + value : value + (sep_by_space === 1 ? ' ' : '') + symbol + (sep_by_space === 2 ? ' ' : '') + sign + signPadding;
        break;
      }
    }

    var padding = width - repl.length;
    if (padding > 0) {
      padding = new Array(padding + 1).join(' ');
      // Fix: How does p_sep_by_space affect the count if there is a space? Included in count presumably?
      if (flags.indexOf('-') !== -1) { // left-justified (pad to right)
        repl += padding;
      } else { // right-justified (pad to left)
        repl = padding + repl;
      }
    }
    return repl;
  };

  return format.replace(regex, doReplace);
}
```